# To remove undesired lines using linux command

Tags: linux, unix

I have a csv file(1TB) of the following form:

```
 1     hi hello
 2     users badges
 abc def
 3     questions
 4     tags
 Unanswered answered
```

Whenever I have a string in the beginning of the line, I want to delete that line and whenever I have a number(integer) in the beginning of the line I want to retain that line. 
I want the output in the following format:

```
 1     hi hello
 2     users badges
 3     questions
 4     tags
```

Is it possible to achieve it using a linux command. I know it is possible to achieve this using a programming language like python but is it possible to achieve using cat and sed, etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `grep` to filter lines:

```
$ cat > a_file
 1     hi hello
 2     users badges
 abc def
 3     questions
 4     tags
 Unanswered answered
$ grep '^ *[0-9]' a_file > a_file.modified
$ cat a_file.modified
 1     hi hello
 2     users badges
 3     questions
 4     tags
$ mv a_file.modified a_file
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response. Its very helpful. Can you please explain a bit as to what do the individual commands do

Comment: @JannatArora, `cat > a_file` used to make a sample file to test.

Comment: @JannatArora, `grep '^ *[0-9]' > a_file.modified` used to filter lines that starts with digits (with optional spaces)`, then save modified output to `a_file.modified`.

Comment: @JannatArora, `mv a_file.modified a_file`: overwrite `a_file` with modified lines.

Answer (score 2):

```
sed '/^[^0-9].*/d' test.txt
```

That deletes any lines that don't start with 0-9 in file test.txt

Comment: +1 for the elegant choice. Most often `sed` is only associated with replacement.